# Explorers have not mixhash

Tags: hash, ethash

Why do ethereums explorer (like blockchain.com or etherscan.io) , have not mixhash in block  information? Only Nonce. And why nonce in block explorer on blockchain.com is always 0?

Comment: Those explorer are third parties and they show whatever data they want. It seems nobody cares too much about mixhash to complain. Other explorers show non-zero nonce for pow blocks so I'd say it is a bug or a limitation on blockchain.com, again if nobody complains too much they will not fix it.